# generate more than one select for HABTM - simple_form and RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

When using simple_form and creating a field for a HABTM associated model, we obtain a select box that accepts multiple options.

Is there any way of having multiple select boxes that accept a single option?

If we have categories, for example:

```
Category1 => <select>options...</select>
Category2 => <select>options...</select>
Category3 => <select>options...</select>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following models:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongts_to_many :businesses
```

You can use the following rails helper to show a select box for each category.

```
- @business.categories.each do |c|
      = f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {:selected => c.id}, {:name => 'business[category_ids][]'}
```

Then you can use javascript to dynamically create new select boxes. [This railscast explains the basics.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

Within a simple_form_for eg states/regions

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
```

(leaving out unnecessary form elements for clarity)

```
<%= simple_form_for @state do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :regions, as: :check_boxes, collection: Region.all.sort, :selected => @state.regions, :label => false %>
<% end %>
```

This will display all Regions (obviously you can filter it) as a list of checkboxes, with those already recorded being selected